# Why can't I find the asset folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I am building my first windows azure application.
I followed the procedure as mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg712344.

But I encountered a problem in the third step of task 3. According to that, I have to add the main page and its associated assets to the web role. But when i select add an existing item, i cannot find any Assets folder.

Did i make a mistake while following the procedure? I stored the new project in G drive. Should that matter? 
I tried the same steps twice and could not find the assets folder in both the cases.

Also, I have downloaded the trial version of visual studio 2010 and am working with that.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find those files in the download here:

http://az12722.vo.msecnd.net/vs2010trainingcourse2-0/labs/introtowindowsazurelabvs20102-0/Source.zip